# Extra padding in UITableViewCell with multiple lines of text

Tags: uitableview, swift, autolayout, height, cell

Why is this happening? I'm not using IB by the way.

**CODE:**

```
cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NormalCell") as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]["text"] as? String
```

**IMAGES:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this question with auto layout, how are you setting this up, can you show the constraints? How are you calculating the row height?

Comment: not calculating the row height, ios8 can do that automatically. It's overshooting the row height. The constaints I have set for the tableview are top space to superview, leading space, trailing space, and bottom space, all set to 0

Comment: I had a similar issue where there was extra space above and below my `UILabel`. I solved that buy adding `[myLabel setContentHuggingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the constraints properly. Check out my screenshots below!

1) Set Constraints

http://prntscr.com/6r5i2z

2) Check Table Properties

http://prntscr.com/6r5i8y

3) Run the project! That's it!

Let me know, if you have any other issues!

Comment: what is the last constraint you have for your tableview? It's cut off.